# Pushing files over 100MB to GitHub

Tags: git, github

I am trying to push files over 100MB to Github. I have tried all the options I could find, including the GitHub large file extension, but no luck.

I am trying to push from GitHub Desktop currently, as I am pushing over 100 files and this is a workaround, but hoping someone can provide me with some advice or the exact steps to push files over 100MB.

The photo below is what I am getting when trying to do so (file names blurred out due to confidentiality).

[image]

Comment: _Why_ do you want to version such very large files?  Are these binaries of some kind?  Consider storing them somewhere else than GitHub.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I want to push so all these files can be accessed by another developer

Comment: Don't do it.  Git does not handle very large binary files.  There is a reason why GitHub is trying to block you from doing this.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen what's the best alternative then?

Comment: What was the issue with using git-lfs?

Comment: @ZoisTasoulas I don't quite understand how the LFS extension is supposed to help. If GitHub doesn't like big pushes (which isn't weird), what difference does it make to apply LFS and store large files regardless? The space needed for storage is still the same, the payload of moving the data is still the same. What is the difference? (NB I'm not questioning the suggestion. I simply dislike magic and prefer to understand why it works instead of happily accepting that it works.)

Comment: @KonradViltersten Not sure how github orchestrates the LFS implementation. My assumption is that they route LFS traffic to different servers. That way they can manage better the bandwidth and responsiveness of the main service.

Answer (score 13):

> GitHub has a strict file limit of 100MB. So, It's recommended to use Git Large File Storage for your use case.

[Git Large File Storage](https://git-lfs.github.com/) lets you store large files on a remote server such as GitHub.

Download & install git-lfs by placing it into your $PATH.

***Run the following command once per local repository:***

```
git lfs install
```

***Large files can be selected by :***

```
git lfs track '*.nc'
git lfs track '*.csv'
```

It will create a file named `.gitattributes`, and now you can perform add & commit operations as normal.

Now,

1. Push the files to the LFS,

2. Push the pointers to GitHub.

***Here are the commands:***

```
git lfs push --all origin master
git push -u origin master
```

If you wish to pull the repository on another device, simply install `git-lfs` on that device(per local repository).

Comment: okay okay.... eventough i already have the "git add ."
executed earlier and then now i executing new command as you mentioned ;
"git lfs install" under the same directory right? Everything is not going to be messed up? @AmitKumar